# Is there an alternative to Cocoa Sourceview for Qt on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa, widget

Would anyone happen to know if [Cocoa SourceView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html) exists for Qt on Mac? I can't seem to find any info online and am not sure if this needs to be written by hand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a similar tool? If yes, this is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In general case you must understand that SourceView is program written using Objective-C/Cocoa. So you can't find exactly same program written using C++/Qt.

But, if you reduce your requirements, you can find some components and even programs written using C++/Qt that can fit your needs.

As quick answer, I say that you need to write all by hand. But you can find lot of ready to use components and source code snippets.

Take a look at [Qt Model/View programming](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) approach. There is [`QFileSystemModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html). Dig in that direction.

Also, there are lot of resources to read about such kind of programming:

- [Simple file explorer using the QFilesystemModel along with a QTreeview and a QListview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92biLZST6Vg) -- 49th tutorial on Qt by VoidRealms.
- [Qt5 Tutorial ModelView with QTreeView and QFileSystemModel](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTreeView_QFileSystemModel_ModelView_MVC.php)
- ...

Hope it helps. Good luck!